# Connecting in PyQt4 QMessageBox fails to call the slot method

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-signals, qmessagebox

I was trying to analyse the sample code cited here: [PyQt - QMessageBox](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qmessagebox.htm)
Here's the snippet:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        w = QWidget()
        b = QPushButton(self)
        b.setText("Show message!")

        b.clicked.connect(self.showdialog)
        w.setWindowTitle("PyQt Dialog demo")

    def showdialog(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)


        # self.connect(msg, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.msgbtn)
        msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.msgbtn)

        msg.exec_()

    def msgbtn(self, i):
        print("Button pressed is:", i.text())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

There are two ways of connecting signals to slots in PyQt. For buttons, it's:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL(“clicked()”), slot_function)
```

or

```
widget.clicked.connect(slot_function)
```

Using it the second way works fine: the `msgbtn` slot method is called as intended. However, if I try to change it to the more usual, 'PyQt-onic' way of connecting (i.e. the first one - I commented it out in the snippet), the slot method is never called. Could anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the signal you pass to SIGNAL is incorrect, the QMessageBox does not have the clicked signal but the signal is `buttonClicked (QAbstractButton *)` so the correct thing is:

```
self.connect(msg, SIGNAL("buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)"), self.msgbtn)
```

On the other hand that is not the *PyQt-onic* style, but the old style which is not recommended to use, but we recommend using the new style.

Old style:

```
self.connect(msg, SIGNAL("buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)"), self.msgbtn)
```

New style:

```
msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.msgbtn)
```

For more detail read the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Obviously, the book and sites I read on the topic are obsolete, so I was misled to think that the first way was the right one. It does work with the `QAbstractButton *` param, even though I don't understand what it is and the docs don't shed light on that. Regardless, it seems to be superfluous in the new succinct style, which is fine with me. Thank you!

Comment: @VladimirMorozoff Here is the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#buttonClicked , if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour], that's the best way to thank ;)

Comment: @VladimirMorozoff On the other hand PyQt4 is very old, I recommend learning PyQt5, it has many more modules and it is continuously improving. ;)